# ABP swagger can't authorize

Tags: swagger-ui, abp

I'm using `abp.io` IdentityServer4 separated (tiered) solution, I see that `Swagger UI` has the following endpoints, but when I call them, I'm getting error 401 (not authorized), also Swagger UI doesn't have Authorize button by default.

How should I solve the issue, to be able to call those endpoints?

[image]

Here's the error response I get:

```
{
  "error": {
  "code": null,
  "message": "Authorization failed! Given policy has not granted.",
  "details": "AbpAuthorizationException: Authorization failed! Given policy has not granted.\r\nSTACK TRACE:    at 
  ...
}
```

Comment: Please post your controller code with annotations and any other relevant [configurations](https://docs.abp.io/en/abp/4.4/API/Swagger-Integration).

Comment: [docs.abp.io/en/abp/5.1/API/Swagger-Integration#using-swagger-with-oauth](https://docs.abp.io/en/abp/5.1/API/Swagger-Integration#using-swagger-with-oauth)